# How Much Would The Creeper Enchantment Benefit Someone?

Tags: magic, humans

The Creeper Enchantment is simple in principle; it simply grants a creature mobility it doesn’t normally have. The Enchantment itself is gained from Reapers, mutated and magically supercharged vampire bats, and is derived from vampire bat’s unusual mobility-they can run and jump, are surprisingly acrobatic, when most bats can barely walk and are really best at flying. Vampire bats may even be able to leap straight up from the ground and fly, if I recall correctly this ability should be unique.

The question here is whether its actually useful for humans, and here’s why: this “Enchantment” modifies the body, much like Rubberization and Calcification, and on humans it allows one to move on all fours. The normal human’s not built for that, ladies and gentleman, it’s remarkably uncomfortable, somewhat detrimental (arms aren’t exactly made to hold us up) and results in awkward adjustment (bottom in the air) due to physiology.

This Enchantment would, to put it bluntly, change that. It would make both sets of limbs the same length, adjust musculature to enable bipedal and quadrupedal movement without awkwardness, and enable greater weightbearing for the arms.

At first blush, yes, it may seem useless, but I would point out:

- Arms as long as legs-longer reach
- Being able to move more effectively on all fours-and stay level doing it-would likely aid in sneaking (lower profile, no bottom sticking up in the air, potentially much faster) and climbing (ever climbed up a rugged slope because walking bipedally doesn’t work?)
- People live without shoes and do just fine with calloused soles for protection, hands callus too. Sturdier hands and potentially more prehensile feet will either aid in survival (tougher hands-harder to hurt-stronger arms behind hands-harder hits) or locomotion (can grip with feet and hands).
- With arms stronger and sturdier to help support weight, and quadrupedal jump capability (which would make arms even more capable of hitting harder), arm strikes would be a lot harder-particularly palm strikes due to calloused palms
- Being adapted so that running all fours is a viable option means potentially greater speeds overall (which would incentivize doing so, because we love speed)

But, even with that reasoning, I am no expert, so here's I'm asking: **how much would the Creeper Enchantment really benefit humans?**

1. The best answer will account for the potential benefits of quadrupedal movement capability (those Enchanted will be capable of bipedal movement as well) to someone with this Enchantment.
2. The best answer should also account for the benefits of enhanced arm length, strength and durability to a holder of this Enchantment
3. And, assuming prehensile feet also occurs (which is likely considering human similarity to simians) the benefits there should be accounted for as well.
   **4. The benefits should cover survival, stealth, travel, and self-defense, ie. will this Enchantment actually help someone in life and if so, how much. If it has drawbacks, or problems, please let me know.**

**Thank you for your feedback!**

**Clarification:**

1. The Creeper Enchantment is based off of how vampire bats have unusual mobility among bats, other bats technically *can* walk, but they can't do it well enough to also run and jump grounded like vampire bats can. Just like how humans can **technically** move on all fours but it doesn't work super well. The Creeper Enchantment gives them that extra option, if that makes sense.

Comment: Ah yes the vampire bat enchantment. Probably something about drinking blood? Nope. Echolocation? Nope! Flight! Not even close! FOUR LEGS!?

Comment: Arms as long as legs-longer reach means that it won't only your bottom sticking up while going on all four, but your entire back. I would therefore challenge that this enchantment helps for being sneaky.

Comment: If I understand the Q correctly, you've basically created a spell, let's rename it "Lycanthropic Allure" that causes people to temporarily become werewolves. I get it, no fur, no snout, no mindless desire to raid chicken coops... but still, you're turning people into human-looking dogs. It's also obvious from the question that you've already developed a use for this. Since the [help/dont-ask] says providing your As is verboten and your "at first blush" list is dangerously close to exactly that.... why are you asking the Q? What's wrong with the A you have? Or are you just brainstorming?

Comment: @JBH: ah, good point, I'm asking for the specific reason that I am not a biological expert and the modifications involved here would modify and therefore impact Enchanted humans, and I want to fully understand what that impact will be. I will see about editing accordingly.

Comment: @L.Dutch: fair enough, you think I should alter that? Or just keep it as is?

Comment: @Daron: Vampirism is the best-known Enchantment result, I decided to go with the other unique thing about vampire bats as an alternate Enchantment one can gain from Reapers. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is the Creeper Enchantment defined here by you, or not?

If not, where is it defined, and why are you Asking about it here?

If it is defined here by you why not make the definition fit your own needs or wants?

Are there other circumstances not covered?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: good questions. I'll see if I can clarify....

Answer (score 12):

### Solution in search of a problem

Humans have power because they are (intelligent) social tool-users. The Creeper Enchantment undermines that. The old saying is "play to your strengths," *not* "play to your least-developed and least important abilities."

Sure, hands can develop callouses. (Until they do, crawling will be painful.) But when your hand is as tough and calloused as your foot, and your fingers have lost significant mobility because they're constantly being crushed into the ground by your weight, your fine motor skills will be seriously harmed. Even the crawling apes that are closely related to humans favor their hind legs for locomotion.

The other "benefits" of the Creeper Enchanment aren't that useful. Unless the humans in question are living in some kind of contrived scenario in which they're constantly required to engage in physical combat and strange acrobatics, or to hunt *unarmed* for their own food, they won't need or really benefit from an enhanced vertical jump. When was the last time *you* really needed to jump 10 feet straight up? It just doesn't happen.

Humans are already plenty sneaky. Making us crawl on four legs instead of two will not really improve that. We don't need an enchantment in order to reduce our profile or move quietly. Worse, our situational awareness will be devastated by anything that interferes with our ability to easily turn our head in any direction to scout the environment. Stealth is not really aided by replacing two ground contact points with four, either: more touch points = more possibility of making noise by touching something, and more tracks left for others to discover.

Humans dominated the planet by relying on specialized abilities, none of which are helped by this enchantment, and several of which are undermined. Yes, if you locked a human and a creeper in a tiny room together, it seems likely the human will fare the worst. But, again, that's a contrived situation. A tribe of humans will defeat a tribe of creepers because the humans will be better able to coordinate and use tools (including ranged weapons), rendering irrelevant the odd locomotion and marginally greater reach.

Answer (score 11):

**It would benefit me a lot.**

Because I am casting it on other people who annoy me.  Strutting around, over 6 feet tall and that without the platform soles they wear.  And why?  Why platforms?  They are already so tall!  Gesturing magnificently, long shiny hair down past the shoulders with that supercilious look in their eyes as they look down on me.  And the swanky scarves!

I would look like that too if it weren't for my trichotillomania keeping me from working out.  But I have the fix for them - the Creeper Enchantment!

Oh your waist length hair is dragging on the ground it is?  Got some bugs in it?  Yes it does.  Maybe you should put it in a bun.  You can use your scarf which is also dragging on the ground.  Haw!  And I am sure the ground appreciates your haughty eyebrows because that is what you look at now.  Hard to make that sweeping hand gesture when your hands are on the ground, you fancy person.  Giddyap now!  Get scuttling, scuttly!

Yes, Creeper Enchantment is to bring those highfalutin folk down a notch.  Let them scuttle around on all 4s as a lesson in humility.  I should mention that this version leaves the butt of the enchanted up in the air.  Most people appreciate that.   I know I do.

Comment: If I remember, the way to give someone an enchantment, you have to trick them into killing a vampire bat. So maybe put a small one in their winter boots and ask them to go put the bins out real quick. Or put the bat on the lip of the toilet seat. Or behind the back wheel of their automobile. Loads of room for hijinks.

Comment: Cook the holiday turkey. Sneak the sleeping vampire bat into the body cavity, give the knife to your victim, and ask them to carve. This sounds much better than all that character class leveling up mumbo jumbo. No one steal my idea.

Comment: @Daron: great idea, thanks for the inspiration! I see I have to make how Classes work clearer as well, that's good to know.

Answer (score 8):

**Climbing**

[image]

Climbing is hard because your legs are bigger than your arms. There is a temptation to pull yourself up with your arms but this tires you out. It is better to use the arms for aiming and the legs for pushing. Legs don't get tired this way because they are legs ad not arms. If you had legs for arms you could do all kinds of crazy manoeuvres in the treetops. I remember your world has trees from the serazor question.

Comment: Upvote for "man oeuvres" because when you left that vampire bat on the toilet seat I got bit right on the man oeuvres.  But I still laughed.  Through the pain, I laughed.

Comment: @Willk By the rules of Alendyias I declare bat now gets whatever enchantment your man oeuvres had. We will have to wait for the next question to find out what means.